# Uniswap path generation

Tags: solidity, remix, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, pairings

The uniswap contract has a function called swapTokensForExactTokens. One of the arguments to this function is an array of addresses called "path" which is the route that the transfer will take.

How is this path generated automatically without having to hard code it assuming that a pair from source token to destination token does not exist.

Uniswap seems to do it automatically.